# AJAX: how to return an error from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form for a user to upload a profile picture and show them live validation without refreshing. I am trying to use AJAX but it does not seem to reach the PHP file. Also even though I am using preventDefault after I submit the form it reloads the page and opens the first tab which does not have the form on.

**FORM**

```
$avatar_form = '<div class="bhoechie-tab-content" id="uploadphoto">';
$avatar_form .= '<center>';
$avatar_form .= '<form id="avatar_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
$avatar_form .= '<h1>Change avatar</h1>';
$avatar_form .= '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
$avatar_form .= '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
$avatar_form .= '<p id="status"></p>';
$avatar_form .= '</form>';
$avatar_form .= '</center></div>';
```

**PHP Snippet**

```
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
    $fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
    if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
        $result = "That image has no dimensions";

        exit();
    }
    $db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
    if($fileSize > 1048576) {
        $result = "Your image file was larger than 1mb";
        echo $result;

    } else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
        $result = "Please only JPG, GIF or PNG images";
        echo $result;

    } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        $result = "An unknown error occurred";
        echo $result;

    }
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#avatar_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'photo_system.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('#status').html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   Sorry worded the question incorrectly basically I want it to return an error to the user for example if the upload is not a supported file format

Comment: Have you checked the console?  What does it say?

Comment: `serialize()` won't upload a file. Do a search for how to upload using ajax. Also you are requesting json and returning text so your `success` will not fire due to parse error. Implement ajax error handler

Comment: @Sablefoste no errors are in the console

Comment: Try `FormData` instead of `serialize()`. Secondly your return type is JSON and you are not returning a JSON object back. You can try  for instance`$result = "An unknown error occurred"; echo json_encode(array('result' => $result);` Then in your ajax success do `$('#status').html(result.result);`

Comment: @charlietfl I am not trying to upload it using the AJAX I am just trying to pass it to the PHP script which works without the AJAX but I am trying to incorporate live validation into the form

Comment: That doesn't make sense based on your form having a file input and the php expecting files. Suggest you update question with full explanation of what you are trying to do

Comment: Also if page is reloading something else is wrong also. That means your submit handler isn't being called when form exists or you have script errors or you have repeated ID's or something

Comment: If there is nothing on the console, then you are not getting `success` (you have a `console.log(result)` in the success callback).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past myself as part of a plugin that has been written, the code that handles the image data and ajax is below:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append($(_file).attr('name'), _file.files[0]);
var _this = this;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: <<URL>>,
   data: form_data,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
})
```

This will submit the image that is loaded in the 'file' dialog box to the server and have it in the expected format for $_FILES superglobal.

Also bear in mind that this is just a snippet of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this Jquery parseJSON function and json_encode:

Keep this PHP code as it is:

```
$Stuff = 'Hello world';

$Success = true;
$Content = $Stuff;

$Response = array('Success' => $Success, 'Content' => $Content);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

And for the JS:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "../pgs/UpdateEditAStudent.php",
    data: "FirstName="+ $('#student_first_name').val(),

    success: function(data){
        // Here is the tip
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);

        alert(data.Content);
    }
});
```